# At what capacitance and voltage are capacitors harmful?

Tags: voltage, capacitor, current, capacitance

I'm currently building a taser from scratch and would like to know which capacitor to use.

Comment: Do you know that in some countries tasers are considered weapons which require a license (or prohibited rightaway)? Although a taser is considered by some as a *non-lethal weapon*, it can indeed kill a person, especially someone with cardiac issues or someone with a lighter body mass (e.g. children). For example (IANAL), in Italy you can *buy* a taser only if you have a license to carry weapons, *but you cannot carry one around*. Check your country legislation before you get into trouble with the authorities.

Comment: Anyway, ***be extremely careful***, any electric device which can cause convulsions (and a taser is meant do do that) is potentially lethal! If someone dies or is severely harmed by such circuit *you will be held responsible*. BTW, from your poorly stated question I guess you are a newbie in electronics. Avoid such dangerous circuits until you know better what you are doing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It needs to be a high voltage capacitor. The idea is high voltage low current.

As for the exact specs, that depends entirely on your circuit. You can google circuits with proper parts lists. Be careful.